# How can I call the latest excel file using python in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I call a spcecific name file, but it is not the last one, thanks.

```
class Tables():
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        frame_results = LabelFrame(frame_bottom, text='Results', font='Verdana 8')
        frame_results.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        self.table=Table(frame_results,dataframe=self.read(),
        showtoolbar=True,
        showstatusbar=True,
        editable=True,)
        self.table.show()
    def read(self):
        data=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\ruben.carballo\Desktop\Nodes_Real_Atr_v2_Plots\Results\1_Test_1.xlsx")
        return data
```

A code solution to solve the problem, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the latest excel file"?

Comment: The OP wishes to get the path of the latest modified/created excel file with out hard-coding them in his code.

Comment: You can't *"call"* an Excel file - it is a passive piece of data, it won't do anything. You can *"open"* it, or *"read"* it or *"load"* it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can utilize the `glob` and `os` module in python to figure out the latest modified file in a directory.

```
import os
import glob

# Directory containing the Excel files
directory = "your_directory_path"

# List all Excel files (.xlsx) in the directory
excel_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.xlsx"))  

# Sort files by modification time in descending order
excel_files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)

# The first file in the list is the most recently modified
latest_excel_file = excel_files[0]
print(f"The latest Excel file is: {latest_excel_file}")
```

It will return you the path of the latest excel file. This script works for other files too, I use this in one of my projects to get the recently created image(.jpg, .png). You can use it to find the latest Excel. If you wish to use it for other files just change the format in `glob.glob()`

Comment: Thank you so much @Musabbir Arrafi for your explanation :). But I want to visualize in a tkinter window the most recent excel, not only the path, many thanks!

Comment: That's simple from here, just put the path in your `data=pd.read_excel(latest_excel_file)`

Comment: Thank you very much Musabbir Arrafi :) , it works!